# UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard () is always << uninitialized >>

Tags: ios, swift, uipasteboard

I want to copy an image to the `UIPasteboard` and paste it e.g. Into WhatsApp.

But this is **not working**.

If I test it on my device, the pasteboard is not set (old copy content) and ff I check it with the debugger, `po pasteboard` always prints `<< uninitialized  >>`.

**My source** (data is set):

```
    let data              = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let pasteboard        = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    pasteboard.persistent = true
    pasteboard.setData(data!, forPasteboardType: "public.png")
```

Comment: If you're checking the description of `pasteboard`, make sure you're checking its value the line after it is assigned.  Otherwise it will return `<< uninitialized  >>` because its value hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes. This was the answer. :)

Comment: I have added the comment as an answer.  Feel free to mark it as accepted if it has helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're checking the description of `pasteboard`, make sure you're checking its value the line after it is assigned. Otherwise it will return `<< uninitialized >>` because its value hasn't been assigned yet.